# Solidity best practice when multiplying with a floating point number

Tags: solidity

What is the best practice when multiplying a floating point number in solidity? Say I want to multiply a `uint256` with `1.25`.

Currently what I do is always as follows:

```
uint256 temp = 5;
uint256 scaleFactor = 10 ** 2;
uint256 result = temp * 125 / scaleFactor;
```

I feel like this might not be the most ideal way, any better ones?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I usually choose a precision factor / scale factor like your calling it, and use it once across all my code.

1e18 is a good one.

Also, implementing it with a library like WadRay (https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/protocol/libraries/math/WadRayMath.sol) or ds-math (https://dappsys.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ds_math.html) so you don't have to worry about it is also a good move.